# need recomendation for form that has 300 fields

Tags: forms, pdf

if you have 300 fields to complete in your application form.
Do you prefer do it online (fill in the website(e-form), of course with save draft feature so you can come back later) or you just download a PDF from that website and you filled it offline on your computer, after that you upload the pdf to that website?

The forms itself for government application form, it has tax fields, company profile, investor profile etc.

Comment: You better have an application (I mean, the mobile app or PC app) to collect all the needed data and then generate the form – saving a lot of data for possible next reusage. 300 fields forms are inhumane.

Comment: The users have to fill out this form? They are on pcs or laptops? A lot of the fields could be prepopulated by a smart app?

Answer (score 1):

This is a lot of fields, so you can not decide based on preference of users here.

My suggestion is that you will have to provide various ways of completing it to the user:

- online with the ability to save drafts, and/or export uncompleted form to continue offline.
- ability to fill pdf, xml, or any other format offline and upload later.
- paper-based form for sending by convetional post. Then you can scan documents and auto-detect fields

etc.